# Javascript : how to get value from a Script Tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the following value from the script below
Use this field to store the Account to which the Opportunity is related

```
<script>sfdcPage.setHelp('Opportunity.Account', 'Use this field to store the Account to which the Opportunity is related');</script>
```

i can get to this script tag by using :

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[6].getElementsByTagName('script')[1];
```

Can you please let me know.
Many thanks.

Comment: let us see the website that you're trying this code on.

Comment: There is a property called `innerHTML`;

Comment: Without knowing the prototype for the sfdcPage, it's hard to give a better option. You can get the content of the script (if it's a part of the page, as opposed to being a linked-to script) by using it's innerText member. i.e `document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[6].getElementsByTagName('script')[1].innerText` From there, you could just grab all of the text between the 3rd and 4th `'` characters. indexOf and substr will do that for you.

Answer (score 3):

I would not recommend putting `script` tags within your tables, etc. In other words, I wouldn't mix `script` tags with other content-related HTML like that. If you want to store little bits of info like that in your HTML for the purpose of JS, I'd use [data attributes](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) instead.

The simple answer to your question though is to just use the `innerHTML` or `innerText` property as follows:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[6].getElementsByTagName('script')[1].innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use innerHtml as

```
document.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[6].
    getElementsByTagName('script')[1].
       innerHtml;
```

**OR**
 
Set an id to get script content as below example

```
<script id='script' type='text/javascript'>
    $('div').html($('#script').html());

    console.log($('script'));
</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBw44/)

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. One solution....

```
 var scrs = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
 var newscr = "";
 for (var i=0; i<scrs.length; i++) {
    newscr = scrs[i].innerHtml.replace('sfdcPage.setHelp(', 'myfunction(');
    if (newscr != scrs[i].innerHtml) {
       eval(newscr);
    }
 }
```

(although parsing / rewriting the javascript is an ugly hack - if it's your code then your reading then you should know what you put in there).